# How to pass a property as an argument for userform controls?

Tags: vba, properties, arguments

### My issue

I'm creating a function that allows me to transition properties of controls, that are in a userform, from one state to another, creating an animation effect such as a custom drop-down list.

However, I can't seem to figure out if there is a way to pass the specific property as an argument, to keep the function more dynamic.

### Simplified Example

```vb
Private Sub test()
    ' Transition the height of Frame1 additional 150
    transition Frame1, "Height", 13, 0.2, 150
End Sub

Private Function transition(obj As Object, objProperty As String, _
    framesPerSec As Integer, sec As Double, increment As Double)
    
    ' Calculate increment steps\time steps
    increment = increment / framesPerSec
    sec = (sec * 1000) / framesPerSec
    
    ' I tried the code below. Might be misunderstanding how `CallByName` works.
    ' I would use this in place of objProperty below
    
    'Dim Prop As Variant
    'Prop = CallByName(Obj, objProperty, VbLet)
    
    Dim index As Long
    For index = 1 To framesPerSec
        ' * Here is the example of what I'm trying to accomplish
        obj.objProperty = obj.objProperty + increment
      
        ' API sleep function (Milliseconds)
        Sleep sec
    Next index
End Function
```

I've tried looking at the VBA `callbyname` method, but can't seem to get it to work. Perhaps I didn't use it correctly when trying it?

I'm happy to take any feedback or help in any direction in how to pass control properties to a function?

Comment: Is `Prop` in `Obj.Prop` the same `Prop` as `Prop` in `Dim Prop As Variant`? In any case, what is it assigned to? Or did you mean to use `objProperty` instead?

Comment: Also, what's the `CallByName` code you've tried? Because the answer most definitely involves it, with `Obj` and `objProperty` as arguments.

Comment: Sorry! Prop should have been the argument objProperty. I was trying to use prop originally to set it to the value of CallByName. Example: Prop = CallByName(Obj, objProperty, VbLet)

Comment: Two things: 1) you should split up the `vbGet` and the `vbLet` invokes, so that you know which one is blowing up when things go wrong - cramming multiple instructions into one is never a good idea, debugging-wise. 2) this site is Q&A, so questions ask a question and answers answer the question - please don't edit solutions into the question. If you want your working code peer reviewed/improved in any way, take a look at [codereview.se]. Cheers!

Comment: Great, thanks for the positive feedback on both!! Will implement both suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at what's being invoked here:

```
Obj.objProperty = Obj.objProperty + Increment
```

Ignoring the fact that you're illegally treating a `String` local/parameter as a member of `Obj`, you have `Obj.objProperty` on both sides of the assignment, so syntactically, we have:

```
[object].[property-let] = [object].[property-get] + [parameter]
```

In other words, there's no way that can work with a single `CallByName` invocation: you need to first compute the RHS of the assignment, and in order to do that you need to invoke the `Property Get` member to *read* the current value, then add the `increment`, and *then* invoke the `Property Let` member to *write* the new value.

```
Dim currentValue As Double
currentValue = CallByName(obj, objProperty, vbGet)
```

So that's the *read* part. Then you can do the *write* part:

```
CallByName obj, objProperty, vbLet, currentValue + increment
```

Not sure what the `Prop` local `Variant` variable would be used for.

Comment: Awesome, That worked!! Great explanation, thank you. I'll add my fixed code as an example.